# jquery-ias : page with some php variable?

Tags: php, jquery-ias

I've a got a "strange problem" with Jquery-IAS (http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/).

Everything is ok when I use a simple page like `index.php` for example but when I use a variable like `index.php?variable=foo` to filter my query with only `"foo"` values in my database (using PDO prepare to have the `$_GET` result), Jquery-IAS doesn't work anymore (infinite loading).

I [read](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/events.html) the support on the website but I couldn't find the answer. I think the "load method" will be the answer but it isn't.

Any idea ?

Edit: this is the error on console when I do the first scroll:

```
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/ch/index.php 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I find the solution.
Just use the `next` event : http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/events.html#next

> Triggered when the next page should be loaded. Happens before loading
>   of the next page starts.
>
> With this event it is possible to cancel the loading of the next page.
>   You can do this by returning false from your callback.
>
> Say you want to stop loading more pages if you hit a certain url:

```
ias.on('next', function(url) {
    if (url.match(/page3\.html/)) {
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13999996)